# Looping over input elements with jQuery each()

Tags: jquery

I have  written some code that basically attach handler to onsubmit event, but there is a bug that I don't know how to fix.The problem is that when input fields in the form are empty , and code enters the `if` block, it doesn't stop after return statement, ajax code below is also executed, but I don't understand why ?

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('form').bind('submit', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $('form input').each(function() {
            if( !$(this).val()) {
                $(this).addClass('warning');
                return;
            }
        });


        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',

         });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is your `return` intended to stop the ongoing loop of the `each` statement? AFAICT it will just return from that inner function, which it would do anyway.

Comment: you're returning from the `.each` which has no effect (unless you explicitly `return false` from .each which stops iteration, `return`ing non-false will simply skip to the next iteration) and you're not returning from the submit handler.

Comment: I see...what would be the solution then ?

Comment: From the manual: _You can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning false._ http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: (Btw, if you could use appropriate titles it would be a great help. Every single question here could probably be listed as _Bug in code, looking for fix_!)

Answer (score 4):

When you are telling the JavaScript to exit out of the each() block and not the bind block. One way to handle this would be to set a boolean during the each block to false if the val() is empty. After the each block is complete then you can check the boolean and submit the form if it is still true. See code example below:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('form').bind('submit', function(event) {
        var submit = true;
        event.preventDefault();
        $('form input').each(function() {
            if( !$(this).val()) {
                $(this).addClass('warning');
                // this is returning out of this block
                submit = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (submit) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://example.com/',
                dataType: 'json',
               type: 'GET',

            });
         }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'd improve this by returning false inside the each, so the loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from the anonymous function you created in the call to `each`. Instead you should do something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('form').bind('submit', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var has_empty = false;
        $('form input').each(function() {
            if( !$(this).val()) {
                $(this).addClass('warning');
                has_empty = true;
            }
        });

        if(has_empty){
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',

         });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from the callback function that you are using in the `each` call, that doesn't exit from the event handler.

Set a variable to flag the status:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('form').bind('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var ok = true;
    $('form input').each(function() {
        if( !$(this).val()) {
            $(this).addClass('warning');
            ok = false;
        }
    });

    if (ok) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',

      });
    }
  });
});
```